# useDelimiter for any number of whitespace characters in combination with other delimiters?

Tags: java, arraylist, delimiter

I'm trying to make a program to just derive a user-entered polynomial. I'm trying to account for things like "`3x2 + 5x4 + 3`" instead of just "`3x2+5x4+3`". I currently have the delimiter setup as `scan.useDelimiter("[A-Za-z\\s+-]");`. I thought this would cover any letter, the + or - symbols, as well as ANY number of whitespace characters? But when I put the input as something like "`3x2 + 5x4 + 3`" the scanner just stops at that point when I'm using scan.nextInt().

I'll throw in the relevant parts of the code that I'm using to test stuff out. I'm sure there's much more efficient routes(maybe a HashMap, and removing the constant from the list, etc) but I'll worry about that after I get something like this figured out!

```
ArrayList<Integer> coeffArr = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> expArr = new ArrayList<>();
String polynomial;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Write your polynomial in the form of (coefficient)(variable)(exponent). (ie: 3x2 is 3x squared):");
polynomial = scan.nextLine();

scan = new Scanner(polynomial); 
scan.useDelimiter("[A-Za-z\\s+-]");

while(scan.hasNextInt())
{
    coeffArr.add(scan.nextInt());

    if(scan.hasNextInt())
        expArr.add(scan.nextInt());
}

if(coeffArr.size() != expArr.size())
    constant = coeffArr.get(coeffArr.size()-1);

for(int i = 0; i < expArr.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.print( (coeffArr.get(i) * expArr.get(i)) + "x" + (expArr.get(i)-1) + " ");
}
```

So essentially, if I put the input as "`3x3+5x2+4`" it will output "`9x2 + 10x1`", but if I were to do "`3x3 + 5x2 + 4`" all I'll get in the output is "`9x2`". How do I fix that and why does it happen?

Comment: Why dont you remove all the whitespaces before parsing the string?

Comment: Your delimiter needs a `+` at the end: `scan.useDelimiter("[A-Za-z\\s+-]+");`

Comment: `useDelimiter` only affects calls to `next`. It won't change the behavior of `nextInt`

Comment: @4castle That + made it work just fine hah. What does the + outside of the brackets do just out of curiosity? And I didn't know `useDelimiter()` only affected `next()`, interesting! But if it only affects `next()` then why does changing the delimiter in this scenario work? Is it because `nextInt()` calls next itself? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Zyga I was tempted to just use `replaceAll(" ","")` but I wanted practice with useDelimiter due to my unfamiliarity with it.

Comment: The `+` means the delimiter can be one or more of the characters inside the brackets. The syntax for `useDelimiter` is that of a regex. The syntax for a regex is found in the documentation for [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy).

Comment: Ah okay, thank you so much again!